# How can I parseFloat more than one selected attribute and add them together?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got an element stored within a div with `data-price` attribute. I'd like to `parseFloat()` its value once it has been selected. I achieved that using following script:

```
var sum = parseFloat( $(".select").data('price')); 

$('#sum').html(sum);
```

However, once the price has been fetched, it is replaced with another price upon clicking  on different element instead of appearing next to it. What is the best method of storing the prices of all selected elements? I was thinking about storing the values in an array so that I can use for loop to calculate the total, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Also, maybe there's more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Note that jQuery's `data()` does type conversion automagically ?

Comment: When clicking the next element, just do `sum += something` to add to it

Comment: What's the point of parsing a string into a float if then you coerce it back to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
var sum = 0

$(".select").each(function(selected) {
    sum += $($('.select')[selected]).data('price')
})

$('#sum').html(sum);
```

This works because $() returns an array with the element search for and .each return the index of the element it has come to so `$($('.select')[selected])` first gets all classes with select then choose the index and makes it to an jQuery object so we can use .data and get the price.
For keeping it update you could

```
$('.elements').click(function() {
    // add all the code above here
})
```

Comment: jquery doesn't have a `forEach` function, and `sum` will append the price instead of performing addition, as using `attr()` will retrieve the prices as strings

Comment: Sorry @billyonecan I see  but I found .each which should make it work, so there are no problems anymore

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer. I'm new to jquery and this approach is very clear to me. I need, however, a small adjustment. If I select 2 elements with prices 10.99 and 11.99 responsively and unclick them, then I'm left with sum  being set to either 1 or -1. The calculation is correct, but the effect I'd like to achieve is sum being set to 0 while nothing is selected. Any idea how to tweak it?

Comment: @Scarto this should work fine. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/n8v82g0v/1/)

Comment: It does work great indeed! I had to tweak around a bit to implement it to my code's architecture but I managed to get it working. Thank you :)